# What is the discounted (4%) difference in health outcomes between Treatment A and Treatment B using ICER, QALY and utility value?

Tags: economics, utility

I'm studying health economics and have been racking my brain trying to find the right answer to this problem, but I keep getting it wrong no matter what I do. I haven't had any trouble calculating ICER, QALY and DALY until now and none of my textbooks have examples that include discounting the costs and effects. Hopefully someone here can help before I give up.

Formula used:

[image: ICER formula]

There are two different treatmeants for a health injury that take place over two years:

1. Treatment A: Takes place over two years, has costs and effects in both years of the treatment.
2. Treatment B: Takes place in the first year and therefore only has costs in the first year, but this treatmeant has effects in the year after the intervention.

**Costs of treatments**

**Treatment A:**

1st year: 10 400 dollars

2nd year: 10 000 dollars (with a discount of 4 % applied).

**Treatment B:**

1st year: 28 000 dollars

2nd year: 0 dollars

**Saved costs:** the health injury costs 8000 dollars in the first year after the injury.

**Utility value/health outcome in QALY:** 0,55 in the first year after the injury.

**The effects of the treatments:**

Treatment A: 2 injuries avoided every year

Treatment B: 3 injuries avoided in the 1st year, and 2 injuries avoided in the 2nd year.

A discount of 4 % has to be applied to all costs and health outcomes/effects, but only to the the second year, not the first year. This is one of the issues I'm having. I don't know which numbers to apply the discount to. I also can't figure out how much is saved in costs by preventing injury.

Comment: The way I usually compute ICERs between treatment A and treatment B is by estimating the present value of cost of treatment $A$, say $C_A$ and same for treatment $C_B$. Also, the present value of QALYs (or any other utility measure) for treatment $A$, say $E_A$ and for treatment $B$, say $E_B$; this is as if one give a value of one unit of money (dollars for example) per QALY. Then estimate $I=\frac{C_B-C_A}{E_B-E_A}$. (the be continue)

Comment: The issue here is how to estimate $E_A$ and $E_B$. It seems that very injury reduces the utility by $0.55$ (if that is indeed the interpretation here) thus the present value ( at 1 dollar per utility) of QALY  treatment is $E_A=2\cdot0.55*(1.04)^{-1}+2\cdot0.55*(1.04)^{-2}$ for treatment $A$ and $E_B=3\cdot0.55(1.04)^{-1}+2\cdot0.055(1.04)^{-2}$ for treatment $B$.